# ChromeDriverManager.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'print_first_line'

Tags: python

I have tried to run given code , but getting error for cromeDriver, when I run code for amazon, but working fine for flipkart

```
import requests
import PyScrappy
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# Create a new ChromeDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

obj = PyScrappy.ECommerceScrapper()
#data = obj.flipkart_scrapper(name, 10)
search_text = input("Enter your Product: ")
data = obj.amazon_scrapper(search_text, 1)
# This is a simple Hello, World! program
#print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.to_excel(search_text+'.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: PyScrappy is broken

Comment: Please add the error stack trace.